# flutter read data from mysql

Tags: flutter, dart

I just built flutter environment on Mac yesterday and started to learn.
trying to get data from mysql following the tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ig6WRq73iEg&t=165s&ab_channel=JesusHedo

here is my code

mysql.dart file

```
import 'package:mysql1/mysql1.dart';

class Mysql {
  static String host = '127.0.0.1',
      user = 'root',
      password = 'justin',
      db = 'users_test_MAC';

  static int port = 3306;

  Mysql();

  Future<MySqlConnection> getConnection() async {
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
        host: host, port: port, user: user, password: password, db: db);

    return await MySqlConnection.connect(settings);
  }
}
```

related function in main.dart

```
void _getname() {
    db.getConnection().then((conn) {
      // String sql = 'insert into `userstable` values(50,"justin3","jsutin@gmail",26);'; 
      // this describe can work

      String sql = 'select `name` from `userstable` where id = 20;';
      conn.query(sql).then((results) {
        for (var row in results) {
          setState(() {
            name = row[0];
          });
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

however it didn't work.

in debug mode, it showed var is empty while the describe worked when I queried in mysql workbench

BTW, I've tried to insert data and it can work
If anyone knows there got something wrong

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't work like that.. you need a backend service and work with http client

Comment: OK is there any references recommended?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).